# How to configure commit option for ejbs in Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, transactions, ejb, wildfly, commit

I'm in the process of upgrading jboss from 4.2 to Wildfly 10.

As part of the EJB configuration, in the META-INF folder we have a jboss.xml with container configuration. The configuration is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss>
    <container-configurations>

    <container-configuration extends="Standard BMP EntityBean">
      <container-name>Standard BMP EntityBean with commit option C</container-name>
      <commit-option>C</commit-option>
    </container-configuration>

    <container-configuration extends="Instance Per Transaction BMP EntityBean">
      <container-name>Instance Per Transaction BMP EntityBean with commit option C</container-name>
      <commit-option>C</commit-option>
      <sync-on-commit-only>true</sync-on-commit-only>
    </container-configuration>
  </container-configurations>

  <enterprise-beans>
    <entity>
      <ejb-name>TestEjbEntity</ejb-name>
      <configuration-name>Instance Per Transaction BMP EntityBean with commit option C</configuration-name>
    </entity>
    <message-driven>
      <ejb-name>ASyncActionExecutor</ejb-name>
      <configuration-name>Standard Message Driven Bean</configuration-name>
      <destination-jndi-name>queue/ASyncAction</destination-jndi-name>
    </message-driven>
  </enterprise-beans>
</jboss>
```

How do I do this in Wildfly 10?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to configure it as EJB2 EntityBeans are marked as optional for EE7.
Wildfly does not support the use of EnttyBeans, you should also see a WARN or ERROR message if you try to deploy such appliation.
I recommed to migrate to JPA.